# lc3 Assembly Language Nested Loops

Tags: assembly, nested-loops, lc3

I am trying to print a block of x's for example a 3x4 rectangle using a nested loop in lc3 assembly language and I am having trouble with converting the logic from simple python nested loops into lc3 Assembly language. I am new to this language.

for example this pseudocode here I want to create the same output in lc3 assembly using strictly nested loops. I looked over the web and gave it a shot my self but the only program I could find somewhat similar was a 'hello world' single loop.

Here's the (Python-like) pseudocode:

```
x = 'x'
width = 3
length = 4
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(width):
        print(x, end='')
    print()

#output is 
# xxx
# xxx
# xxx
# xxx
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: I removed the Python tag, as Python is only being used as pseudocode to describe the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Structured statements allow for easy nesting.  A for-loop can have an if-then-else as the body, for example, or, in your case a nested loop.

Assembly languages follow the if-goto-label style, which we can also doin the C language b/c it has goto's and labels.

There is a pattern for every structured statement in assembly language.

Despite the apparent complexity associated with nesting, the assembly language translation should simply follow the pattern for each individual structured statement.

I strongly advocate an approach of simple, logical translations.

Given Python code, I would first translate that into C.  Python has a number of simple features that hide complexity, which needs to be exposed for assembly language.  Fortunately, your example is sufficiently simple, but loop variable increments are hidden.

Next, I advocate running the C code to make sure it works.  Translating C or pseudo code with an error makes for a bad experience!  Further, a tiny algorithmic change or bug fix in C code can have a dramatic effect on the assembly code (possibly so as to require redoing translation rather than applying the same bug fix), so having working code to translate is important.

Given a for-loop, the first thing I do is translate that into a while-loop.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    <i-loop-body>
```

This becomes:

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < N ) {
    <i-loop-body>
    i++;
}
```

Next, we translate the while loop into assembly language's if-goto-label style:

```
    int i = 0;
Loop1:
    if ( i >= N ) goto EndLoop1;
    <i-loop-body>
    i++;
    goto Loop1;
EndLoop1:
```

Let's note a few things:

- The condition test is inverted in if-goto-label because the if-goto statement (also known in assembly language as conditional branch) tells when to stop the loop rather than what we say in C, which is when to continue the loop.
- The loop ends with a label, and this is a natural translation of the structured statement.  It is important that after the loop is done, the machine code moves on to the next statement after, and with this pattern transformation, that will happen naturally: whatever statement succeeds this loop will run next when the loop is finished, as it would in C.  I name labels after the structured statement translation rather than by whatever code happens to follow.
- The processor does not see labels because they are removed by the assembler during translation of assembly text to machine code.  The processor only sees machine code instructions, and labels are not machine code.  Labels affect instructions that use them (i.e. the `goto`s), but they themselves are not part of the resulting machine code program.

To translate multiple loops, whether consecutive or nested, each pattern translation must use a new set of numbers: so to translate another loop, use new labels Loop2 and EndLoop2, throughout that one pattern translation.

If there are multiple while loops to translate, follow the pattern exactly.  Nesting doesn't change the pattern.  As long as you follow the pattern literally, the assembly code will behave the same as the C code.

You can translate an inner loop first, or an outer loop first.  It doesn't matter.  You can also translate in program order, but that is more difficult since you have to bounce back and forth between multiple patterns and their piece parts.

In my examples above, if i-loop-body itself has another loop, then simply place the translation for that where i-loop-body appears.

So, let' say we started with:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    for ( int j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        <j-loop-body>
```

In the above, the i-loop-body is the entire for-j loop.

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < N ) {
    int j = 0;
    while ( j < M ) {
        <j-loop-body>
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

In partial if-goto-label, with only the outer loop transformed:

```
    int i = 0;
Loop1:
    if ( i >= N ) goto EndLoop1;
    int j = 0;
    while ( j < M ) {
        <j-loop-body>
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    goto Loop1;
EndLoop1:
```

In partial if-goto-label with only the inner loop transformed:

```
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < N ) {
        int j = 0;
Loop2:
        if ( j >= M ) goto EndLoop2;
        <j-loop-body>
        j++;
        goto Loop2;
EndLoop2:
        i++;
    }
```

Then with both transformed:

```
    int i = 0;
Loop1:
    if ( i >= N ) goto EndLoop1;
    int j = 0;                                 i-loop-body, j-loop start
Loop2:                                          "
    if ( j >= M ) goto EndLoop2;                "
    <j-loop-body>                               "
    j++;                                        "
    goto Loop2;                                 "
EndLoop2:                                      i-loop body, j-loop completed 
    i++;
    goto Loop1;
EndLoop1:
```

The translation of Loop2, including the the initialization of `j` belongs exactly where the i-loop-body goes, by simple pattern substitution.

Many who start assembly language without a pattern approach will make simple errors in their control structures.  For example, erroneously move the `int j = 0;` part to the very top of the snippet, next to `int i = 0;` where it will work for the first execution of the nested loop, but won't work thereafter.  Another example is forgetting sequential statements, here, that might mean using `goto Loop1;` inside loop 2 (to exit the inner loop), accidentally skipping the `i++;` that should execute each time after loop 2 is completed.